# Eigenfunctions of the Laplacian with imaginary eigenvalue

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are all the $\pm i$ eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or on some domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

I know of a few: things like $e^{e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}x} + e^{e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}y}$ or $e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{ i \frac{\pi}{4}}x} e^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}y}$. Are there others?

Answer (score 0):

You may find a bunch! Consider

$$ \Delta u = \lambda u $$

on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose that $u$ can be split into $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are to be determined. If we plug this into the above equation we obtain:

$$ \frac{ X''}{X} + \frac{Y''}{Y} = \lambda $$

From here we see that there infinitely many eigenfunctions for any given lambda. Why? Since we can shift a term over and obtain a LHS in $x$ and a RHS in $y$ we know that must be a constant:

$$ -\frac{ X''}{X}  = -\lambda +  \frac{Y''}{Y} = \xi $$

where $\xi \in \mathbb{C} $ . Thus we obtain:

$$ X'' = \xi X \quad \& \quad Y'' =(\xi + \lambda) Y$$

Solving these give you a 1-parameter family of eigenfunctions.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any non-separable solutions? I know of the Hankel function of the first kind and order zero; I was hoping all possible solutions are known.

Comment: To obtain the Bessel eigenfunctions, repeat the same argument but in polar coordinates. That completely characterizes everything in $\mathbb{R}^2$. That's all of them by uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This answers the wrong question, sorry.  I'll delete it soon.

Your question seems to be asking something different from the title.

To address the title: the Laplacian doesn't have any imaginary eigenvalues.  On a bounded domain with appropriate boundary conditions, it's a self-adjoint operator and all its eigenvalues are real.  On $\mathbb{R}^n$, it has no eigenvalues at all (but its spectrum is still real).

**Explanation**: I was thinking of the Laplacian as a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.  In that case the functions you exhibited are not eigenfunctions because they are not in $L^2$.  Or, if we work on a bounded domain, then in order to make the Laplacian self-adjoint we need boundary conditions, and I suppose the functions you gave will not be able to satisfy those boundary conditions.e

Comment: I don't understand: didn't I provide examples of eigenfunctions of the Laplacian with eigenvalue i?

Comment: I seem to have answered a different question.  See edit.